# Unable to retrieve student details from the Google Classroom API

Tags: java, android, google-classroom

I am trying to retrieve all the students of a given classroom with the help of the Classroom API (in Java) in my android project. I am able to retrieve the courses and submissions of a course successfully, but it throws some permission error in the message of the exception.

I have referred the official docs for choosing the scopes:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth

The code that throws the exception:

```
ListStudentsResponse studentsResponse = mClassroomService.courses().students().list(courseId).execute();
```

The scopes I have included:

```
new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY),
new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_GUARDIANLINKS_STUDENTS),
new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_PROFILE_EMAILS),
new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY),
new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_PROFILE_PHOTOS)
```

The error message I get from exception

```
    403 Forbidden
    {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "The caller does not have permission",
          "reason": "forbidden"
        }
      ],
      "message": "The caller does not have permission",
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
```

The constants defined..

```
public static final String CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly";

public static final String CLASSROOM_GUARDIANLINKS_STUDENTS = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students";

public static final String CLASSROOM_PROFILE_EMAILS = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails";

public static final String CLASSROOM_PROFILE_PHOTOS = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos";

public static final String CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly";
```

Comment: the error seems quite clear: your user either isn't authenticated, or he has no access to that data

Comment: The user has been authenticated, I am able to fetch the course details and well the submission details of a given course work. I get this error when I try to retrieve the student details. I have added the required scope as per the docs.

Comment: You need to add Roster scope as well but I am not sure about this 

    `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly`

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Thanks a lot! It's finally working now.

Comment: This error means the authenticated user does not have permission to view student details for this course (that is to say, if the user tried to access this from the UI, they wouldn't be able to access this either). Since you mentioned this is working now, can you please post an answer explaining what modification you made for this to work?